# How to refine generic WeakTypeTag inside quasi-quote macro

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

We have the following typeclass

```
trait Mapper[A,M[_]]{
  def map[B](a:M[A], f:A => B):M[B]
}
```

For which we would like to provide instances for specific M. A naive implementation would look like the following:

```
def materializeMapperImpl[A : c.WeakTypeTag,M[_]](c:blackbox.Context)(implicit mTypeTag:c.WeakTypeTag[M[A]]): c.Expr[Mapper[A,M]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val aType = weakTypeOf[A]
    //println(mTypeTag.toString())
    c.Expr[Mapper[A,M]]{

      q"""
         new Mapper[$aType,$mTypeTag]{
            def map[B](a1:$mTypeTag, f: $aType => B): $mTypeTag = {
              ???
            }
          }
       """
    }
  }
```

However, this won't compile because the `mTypeTag` is not refined in its generic arguments and would rather look as `List` rather than `List[Int]` and `List[String]`. How do we refine the mTypeTag, setting its argument to A and B in the macro?

Comment: Depending on how you are going to implement the `???`, you may be able to move it out of the quasiquote, say you define `trait ConcreteMapper[A, M[_]] extends Mapper[A, M]` with a concrete `map` implementation. Then in the quasiquote you can return a `ConcreteMapper[$aType, $mTypeTag]`.

Comment: My problem is expressing the signature of the method map inside the quasiquote , since it requires the types M[A] and M[B]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package so

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

trait Mapper[A, M[_]] {
  def map[B](a: M[A], f: A => B): M[B]
}


object Mappers {
  def f[A, M[_]]: Mapper[A, M] = macro impl[A, M]

  def impl[A, M[_]](c: blackbox.Context)
                   (implicit
                    a: c.WeakTypeTag[A],
                    m: c.WeakTypeTag[M[_]]
                   ): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._


    val ma = m.tpe match {
      case TypeRef(pre, sym, args) =>
        import compat._
        TypeRef(pre, sym, List(a.tpe))
    }
    //attention it is : new packageName.className {}
    val tree =
      q"""
       new so.Mapper[${a.tpe},$m]{
        override def map[B](a:$ma,f:($a) => B) = ???
       }
     """

    q"$tree"
  }
}
```

//test

```
Mappers.f[Int,Option]
```

Comment: Excellent, would you explain why you needed to generate the type and why you interpolated ${a.tpe} instead of $a inside the quasiquote?

Comment: Where both can be :)